# AppOptics "There is no data available at this time interval"

Tags: loggly

Giving a try to Loggly / AppOptics.

I connected a Linux host and started getting some stats for the host.

I then added Nginx and Mysql plugins following the setup instructions, but in the dashboards for Nginx/Mysql for every metric I see "There is no data available at this time interval."

Is there something else I need to do?